# Get the employees who have more than one phone number with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one is **employees** and another one is **details**. Here I need the query to display the employees who are having multiple phone numbers.

**Employees table:**

```
employee_id   Name         salary
-----------  -------  --------------------
0001           John         100000
0002           Peter        50000
0003           Russel       60000
0004           Bill         60000
0005           Patrick      90000
```

**Details Table** :

```
employee_id   Address         phone
-----------  -------  --------------------
0001           USA         854646542
0002           Germany     656562354
0001           USA         465222333
0004           China       888444444
0005           Canada      012445869
0005           Canada      789875877
0003           Japan       444555807
```

From this I need to display employees who are having more than one phone number so the expected output should be

```
employee_id   Name         phone
-----------  -------  --------------------
0001           John         854646542
0001           John         465222333
0005           Patrick      012445869
0005           Patrick      789875877
```

Query I have tried :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT employee_id, COUNT(*) AS CNT
  FROM details
  GROUP BY employee_id
) AS T
WHERE CNT > 1
```

Comment: Also note there's no point in both `details` and `employees` having `Name`. To get the name use a `JOIN`.

Comment: updated my question @Akina

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses a subquery

```
SELECT employee_id, Name, phone
FROM details
WHERE employee_id IN (
   SELECT employee_id
   FROM details
   GROUP BY employee_id
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

I can also be written using a JOIN:

```
SELECT d.employee_id, d.Name, d.phone
FROM
    details d
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT employee_id
       FROM details
       GROUP BY employee_id
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) p ON d.employee_id = p.employee_id
```

This can also be done using OVER clause

```
SELECT employee_id, Name, phone
FROM (
   SELECT 
      employee_id, Name, phone, 
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id) AS phone_count
   FROM details
) t
WHERE t.phone_count > 1
```

Comment: Hi, Kindly check my edited question. How to display the name when it is not available in the detailis table but available in the employees table?

Comment: If using a join, you don't really need any aggregation here

Comment: @Kindly, then replace details with employees JOIN details

Answer (score 6):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT employee_id, t3.Name, t1.phone
FROM Details t1
JOIN Details t2 USING (employee_id)
JOIN Employee t3 USING (employee_id)
WHERE t1.phone != t2.phone
-- ORDER BY employee_id
```

Comment: @Vicky Updated according to the question edition.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT employee_id, t1.Name, phone
FROM details
JOIN employees t1 USING (employee_id)
WHERE employee_id IN (
   SELECT employee_id
   FROM details
   GROUP BY employee_id
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

This will get with name from 1st table